# How do you use react-hook-form with redux and typescript properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hook-form

After many days of trying to find a guide that would show me all of these things in one example I finally gave up and made something that works via brute force, but I know that this is the wrong way to do it.  I don't know exactly why it's wrong but it cant be as complicated as I have made it out to be here.  These are my requirements:

1. use Redux to maintain application state
2. use React Hook Form for forms
3. use Typescript
4. forms must have client side and server side validation ability

Here is what I have:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { ErrorMessage } from '@hookform/error-message';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { MainMenu } from "./../components/MainMenu";

import { userSignupAction } from '../actions/authenticateActions';

interface FormInputs {
  singleErrorInput: string;
  userName: string;
  password: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

export function Signup(props: any) {
  const { 
    register,  
    formState: { errors },
    setError,
    handleSubmit,
    clearErrors
  } = useForm<FormInputs>();

  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data: FormInputs) => {
    props.dispatch(userSignupAction(data));
  });

  if (props.response.signup.userName) {
    if (!errors.userName) {
      console.log('set username error')
      setError('userName', {
        type: "server",
        message: props.response.signup.userName[0],
      });
    }
  }

  if (props.response.signup.email) {
    if (!errors.email) {
      setError('email', {
        type: "server",
        message: props.response.signup.email[0],
      });
    }
  }

  if (props.response.signup.password) {
    if (!errors.password) {
      setError('password', {
        type: "server",
        message: props.response.signup.password[0],
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <MainMenu role="anonymous"/>
      <div className="center70">
        <h2>Signup</h2>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input {...register("userName", { required: "Username is required"})}
              onClick={() => {
                console.log('clear the error');
                props.response.signup.userName = false
                clearErrors('userName');
              }} />
            { errors.userName && <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="userName" />}
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input {...register("firstName")} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input {...register("lastName")} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input {...register("email", { required: "Email is required"})} />
            <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="email" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input {...register("password", { required: "Password is required"})} />
            <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="password" />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (response: any) => ({
  response
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Signup);
```

Note, this is not me trying to get an answer for my job, this is just me trying to learn this technology correctly.  This code is all my code and not part of any proprietary application (clearly as it is not good)

Please help

More info...

My first challenge here was in trying to get a server side validation failure to show up on the front end.  The way I tried to do this initially was by formatting the response as a json object exactly the way the error object is supposed to look in react-hook-forms, like so...

```
{
  "userName": ["User 'jimbob' already exists"],
  "email": ["User with email address 'jimbob@gmail.com' already exists"],
  "password": ["Password must be at least 6 characters"]
}
```

At first I was expecting this response format to magically populate the error but it did not so this is why I had to add the three clauses to check the props value.  Initially this caused an infinite loop so I had to add the second check to see if errors.fieldName was not truthy and only setError in those cases (great! I thought)

But then the next problem was, what happens when you get a server-side validation error but then the user goes back to fix it.  Well in my opinion this should immediately clear the error the moment the user clicks on the field.  Well this wasn't happening because even though the clearErrors function did it's job, the props check just immediately undid it so i had to add the extra line to set the field in props to false.  yay! now it works, but at what cost?

This code all technically works now, but man is this a wordy piece of code for such a simple form.  I can't believe that this is the right way to do things, it shouldn't take 100+ lines of code to make a simple 5 element form.

Comment: As per my answer. You aren't using anything out of react hook form that validates having it at all.

Comment: I am using react hook form for client side validation such as checking if a particular field is required.

Comment: Okay, but then why do you need redux?

Comment: Redux is being used because it's a good central location for application state and also it is immutable which prevents other problems (same reason I'm using typescript) but the Redux aspect of this problem may be irrelevant to my actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Your existing flow is currently as follows. Submit form -> setResponse -> re-render -> read response -> set errors.

A couple things to note.

1. You should not be using a client side validation tool (ReactHookForm) for server side validation/errors
2. Do not setError within the render method of the component
3. The async wrapper around dispatch is redundant
4. Re evaluate your requirements, because they aren't sensible.

A better flow would be either having your own redux middleware or utilise redux thunk. Change the flow to be:
Submit -> Check for errors -> setErrors via callback -> dispatch response -> set and display response

Comment: Question: you suggest using a server side validation tool, I presume you mean on the backend (my backend is Django).  That's fine, but how to get those validation messages to the front end? do they not at some point have to integrate with react-hook-form?

Comment: No, because react hook form is just local react state and a bunch of event handling abstracted away into a hook. It doesn't do anything special. You can just display any errors you have from the response without putting into react hook form.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you have created yourself the complexity by having three sources of information. The server information, the redux store, react hook form state. Now you need to consolidate the three. I think you should eliminate redux

Comment: So, if i understand what you are saying correctly, you would have (for each input) two separate places in the UI to show errors.  one for the client side errors built into the <ErrroMessage> element and a completely separate one for server side errors?  I think this makes some sense, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating react app with the help of **react-redux** library, there are built-in hooks for,

1. Get the data from the redux state - **useSelector()**
2. And dispatch actions to update the redux state - **useDispatch()**

*Usage of useSelector() :-*

So, you don't need to use following code to map redux state to props.

```
const mapStateToProps = (response:any) => ({
    response
});
```

Simply, you should import useSelector() from react-redux as follows.

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
```

Then you can get whatever data from the redux state to your component.

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user);
```

*Usage of useDispatch() :-*

You can use useDispatch() instead of using props to get dispatch(). This hook returns a reference to the dispatch function from the Redux store. You may use it to dispatch actions as needed.

```
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

You can use dispatch reference wherever you want to dispatch a action, for example in your code instead of using following code,

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data: FormInputs) => {
    props.dispatch(userSignupAction(data));
});
```

you can use dispatch reference that we created as follows.

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data: FormInputs) => {
    dispatch(userSignupAction(data));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try these changes as I think they are good suggestions, but i'm not sure how this helps with the form validation issues and complexity.

Comment: Every time I try to replace the mapStateToProps with useSelector as you suggest it causes an error with <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="userName" /> saying errors is undefined.  I have no idea why.  note my useSelector looks like this: const response = useSelector(state => state.response);   any idea?

Comment: Figured it out and it had nothing to do with the <ErrorMessage errors> thing, it was the line below it that was somehow bubbling up and reporting the error above (will try to explain better in my response to my own question)  thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I took all the advice from the people who commented here and created the following which is much nicer (but could probably still be optimized a bit)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { ErrorMessage } from '@hookform/error-message';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { MainMenu } from "./../components/MainMenu";

import { userSignupAction } from '../actions/authenticateActions';

interface FormInputs {
  singleErrorInput: string;
  userName: string;
  password: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

export function Signup(props: any) {
  const { 
    register,  
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit
  } = useForm<FormInputs>();

  const response = useSelector(state => state.signup);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data: FormInputs) => {
    dispatch(userSignupAction(data));
  });

  const [updateCount, forceUpdate] = useState(0);

  const clearError = (field) => {
    response[field] = false;
    forceUpdate(updateCount + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <MainMenu role="anonymous"/>
      <div className="center70">
        <h2>Signup</h2>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input {...register("userName", { required: "Username is required"})} 
              onClick={() => clearError('userName')}/>
            <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="userName" />
            { response.userName && <span>{ response.userName[0] }</span>}
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input {...register("firstName")} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input {...register("lastName")} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input {...register("email", { required: "Email is required"})} 
              onClick={() => clearError('email')}/>
            <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="email" />
            { response.email && <span>{ response.email[0] }</span>}
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input {...register("password", { required: "Password is required"})} 
              onClick={() => clearError('password')}/>
            <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="password" />
            { response.password && <span>{ response.password[0] }</span>}
          </div>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

Notes: What I have above works and is much better than what I had before but there were still issues.

Issue #1: I have to have two separate elements which are conditionally in the DOM, one for client-side and the other for server-side errors.  This annoys me, so I may make my own abstraction of both of these and put them into my own custom element in the future.

Issue #2: I figured out the problem that I was having (in reference to my comment on Dasun's answer) but it bother's me why this happened this way.  What I had originally was something like this:

```
<ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="userName" />
{ props.response.submit.userName && <span>{ props.response.submit.userName[0] }</span>}
```

This code blew up because once I removed the connect call I no longer had props.response which makes sense, however what made this especially annoying was that the error did not reference the actual line of code that blew up, rather it referenced the line above that, and the error specifically mentioned the "errors" value as being undefined when in fact that was not the case.

Issue #3: This is much better, but it's still very wordy.  It would be nice if someone made a form management module which was pre-made to handle server side errors, honestly it seems ridiculous that this one does not.  I can't imaging any website which would only ever have client side errors.

Comment: I think you have enough consistency to now componentize an input group with props. Interface InputProps { label: string, response: Response, inputProps: { ... ect